# Rails partial form in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with Expenses that belongs_to Vendors.

While the user is adding a new Expense, they might need to add a new Vendor.

I thought I could just add a button and a Vendor partial to the Expense form.

Like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @expense, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
  <div class="span5">
  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#vendorform">
    <p class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-mini">New Vendor</p></a>
    <%= render :partial => "vendors/vendorform" %>
  </a>
  <%= f.association :vendor, :label_method => :vendor_name, :label => 'Vendor', collection: Vendor.order('vendor_name ASC') %>
```

The _vendorform.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div id="vendorform" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vendorformLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
<h4 id="vendorformLabel">Add Vendor</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<%= simple_form_for Vendor.new do |f| %>
      (bunch of fields)
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit 'Save Vendor', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %>
      <a class="btn btn-mini" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

This partial shows up OK.  But, the Vendor record doesn't get created.
The submit of the partial actually somehow triggers the submit for the Expense.  The page comes back with all of the required Expense fields red.

I think it's posting to the Expenses controller when the `f.submit` button in the Vendor partial is pressed !!!

Do I need something in the Expense controller?

Or is there a better way?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are you trying to create the vendor object, by clicking the submit button on the vendor form or by clicking the submit button on the expense form?

Comment: Clicking the button on in the partial Vendor form.  But, it looks like that is posting to the Expenses controller - don't know why?

Comment: Basically you have nested `html` form elements.  You shouldn't be doing that.  You should move the fields in another partial, then render that partial within `fields_for` so that the associations are also automatically created.  Hope this makes sense!

Comment: It does make sense.  If you answer, I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the vendor partial is in the same folder as the expense form? If not you should have

```
<%= render :partial => "folder/vendorform" %>
```

Comment: In this case I'm not sure if you need the :partial either. I think you can just have <%= render "folder/vendorform" %>

Comment: I also see two closing anchor tags </a> in the expense form. Maybe try removing one of them.

Comment: Both forms are in the same expenses folder.  Maybe the _vendorform.html.erb should be in the vendors folder - I'll try that.

Comment: maybe you should show us your logic in the create action for the vendor controller.

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested attributes, you should use the `simple_fields_for` method which help manage associations. Then, remove the submit button for the vendor form and add it to the expense form instead. So the vendor form would be -

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= simple_form_for Vendor.new do |f| %>
  (bunch of fields)
  <% end %>
</div>
```